# ¿Es posible configurar los comandos de GIT para que pueda hacer un push a otra de mis cuentas de GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Hola buenas tengo 2 cuentas de GitHub, una mía personal, y otra la cuenta de clases, donde voy subiendo y actualizando los proyectos de clase, el caso es que en mi PC tengo asociado los credenciales de git con mi cuenta de github de clases, y me interesa hacer un git push a mi otra cuenta personal de github, pero claro me salta el siguiente error:

```
remote: Permission to cuenta1/tiendaMuebles.git denied to cuenta2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cuenta1/tiendaMuebles/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Me dice el error que habilite el acceso, pero no sabría como. Mi pregunta es si puedo hacer uso de git en más de 1 cuenta a la vez sin tener que loguear o desloguear credenciales.

Comment: aquí hay una respuesta que parece haber funcionado a tu pregunta
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71015979/18282475

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien, lo que quiero es poder hacer un push a otra cuenta de github que no es la que tengo actualmente logueada. No es hacer un push al mismo tiempo en 2 cuentas distintas. Voy a cambiar el título por si confunde.

Comment: ah entiendo. en ese caso aquí tienes un tutorial que yo he utilizado para configurar multiples cuentas y poder hacer push a un a cuenta en especifico segun el proyecto. https://www.codigojs.com/github/autentifica-con-multiples-cuentas-en-github-sin-contrasena/

Comment: Parece que son comandos para linux no? No me están terminando de funcionar en windows. Le doy el vistazo aún así, gracias.

Comment: los comandos del ssh-* son globales los puedes ejecutar desde windows tambien. y la carpeta del .ssh  está en el directorio de tu usuario windows por lo general está oculto porque la carpeta tiene un . antes del nombre y por lo general windows oculta esos archivos y carpetas y el comando de nano ese sí es de linux pero podrias buscar el directorio y abrir el archivo con un editor de texto 

y lo demás lo puedes seguir el tutorial como está en el enlace